# Do I need to initialize a variable, even if I know it will be assigned before used?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In an ASP.NET MVC app, I have code that boils down to the following:

```
public ActionResult Test() {
    string query;
    try {
        query = GenerateQueryString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ModelState.AddModelError("error", ex.Message);
    }

    ... do additional validation ...

    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        return RedirectToAction("Success?" + query);
    }

    return View(); // Show validation messages
}
```

The above code has a compile error ... `query` might not be initialized.

However, the logic in the code will clearly initialize `query` before using it.

What is the best way to resolve this issue?

Comment: What is the issue with assiging a default or null value to the variable, concern for speed, memory, other?

Comment: From the answers so far, I don't like the code smell caused by initializing `query` to a value that will never be used.

Comment: If there is no QueryString to be assigned the string value would be equivilent to string.Empty so why not just set the value accordingly, it removes ambiguity and makes the code easier to read.

Comment: If an exception is thrown, then I will never use the `query` variable (because I check `ModelState.IsValid`).  Therefore, it is meaningless to initialize to `string.Empty` or `null` or `"Error"`.  If the compiler is going to force me to choose one, then I guess I'll choose `null`, but what other choices do I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C# compiler is looking at your code and seeing that the value of the variable is initialized in a `try` block and is then used later on. It can see that a logical branch of execution exists where an exception is thrown, is caught, and then the subsequent code is executed with an uninitialized value.

The simplest way to stifle the error is to assign a default value to the field. `null` is sufficient. As you're adding the error to the MVC model state and are checking that value later on before accessing `query`, you shouldn't be in a situation when the default value will matter.

Answer (score 1):

You are wrong, What if GenerateQueryString throws an exception? What will be the value of Query?

You might want to do a query = "Error"; or something in your catch block. This because appareantly you want the application to run if an exception in GenerateQueryString is thrown.

**EDIT**

I would recommend against presetting query with a default value. This because the meaning is different. A default value is different than a certain value at a certain moment. Doing so will also prevent the compiler from warning you when you create a new code path but forget to setup a value for query

Comment: Exactly ... I don't want to use a "default value", because even `null` has meaning (`null` means that my code might need to look for `null` later).  My code knows that either `query` has a value, or `ModelState` has an error, so I was hoping to avoid using a "default value" just to make the compiler happy.

Answer (score 1):

If there is exception in the call to `GenerateQueryString` the value of `query` will be undefined.

Try

```
string query = string.Empty;
```

to have a definite assignment to the variable.
Alternatively, if an exception should abort the execution, this will work too:

```
string query;
try {
    query = GenerateQueryString();
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    ModelState.AddModelError("error", ex.Message);
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Do you think assigning a "dummy value" is a good idea, just to prevent the compiler warning?

Comment: Considering it is the only way to get rid of the warning, yes. Or... make sure your exception handling doesn't continue. Should it?

Comment: There might be many ModelErrors due to validation, so I'd like them all to show, so I'd prefer to avoid short-circuiting.

Comment: The best way is to ensure that the variable has a meaningful value. I personally prefer to throw an exception and abort the method, instead of continuing with some dummy value. However in some test/prototype code, `= string.Empty` or `= null` has it's uses.

Answer (score 1):

The Code is NOT clearly initialized. When the GenerateQueryString() Method throws an Exception, no value will be set. You should set the String to null and check for null before you use it, als you don't break in the catch-block.

Comment: Do you think assigning a "dummy value" is a good idea, just to prevent the compiler warning?

Comment: Since the `catch` part adds a model error (therefore setting `ModelState.IsValid` to `false`), I won't need to null check.

Answer (score 1):

Just because YOU know that it will be initialized (it may not be by the way in your code), the COMPILER can't know that - it's called the [Halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

So the compiler errs on the side of caution, something .net does a lot (e.g., no fallthrough in switch..case).

Answer (score 1):

The thing here is that local variables must be initialized before read - they won't be initialized by default and this prevents from bugs programmers often makes. Some time ago I was looking for the answer to this simple situation:

```
bool a = true, b;
if (a == true) //here everything is OK, because a is initialized
   b = true;
if(b == false) //here you get an error, I thought b == false by default
   return;
```

I found on stackoverflow deep explanations, why it works so(couldn't find at the moment which I was reading). But you can read [Absence of evidence is not evidence of absence](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/12/absence-of-evidence-is-not-evidence-of-absence.aspx) interesting article. Maybe it will explain what I tried to say :)

**Resume:**

In your case you need to initialize `query` or set variable in catch block

Answer (score 0):

Just change the declaration of query in: `string query = string.Empty;`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that query is initialised in the try block, but query is declared in the block above.  You must initialise it at the top level block.

Answer (score 0):

It could just be that your `GenerateQueryString()` throws an exception. Personally, I prefer to initialize my variables, just to be on the safe side. For this reason you might just initialize to query to:

```
string query = String.Empty;
```

It doesn't hurt to be on the safe side.